# ¿Cómo realizar un gráfico combinado de barras y líneas?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quiero realizar un gráfico combinado en donde en el eje x tengo los AÑOS, en uno de los ejes y tengo la cantidad de casos por año (gráfico de barras) y en otro eje y la cobertura de vacunas por año (gráfico de líneas, en este caso son 3 líneas porque son 3 vacunas distintas).

Tengo ambos datos en dos bases separadas. ¿Debería juntar las bases para hacer el gráfico o me lo lee en dos bases distintas?

El gráfico debería quedar algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí un ejemplo de los datos que tengo, ahora están en dos bases pero se podrían juntar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mediante la librería `ggplot2` puedes realizar ese tipo de gráficos. Si pudieses compartir un pequeño ejemplo de los datos que tienes (incluirlo en tu mensaje), podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Ahí agregué los datos como los tengo en 2 dataframes